# Using a variable with multiple values and get through a loop

Tags: applications

I am very new to mathematics but I would like to know if there is a way to use a variable, which has multiple numbers. If so, I would like to create a loop.

Here is an example of what I want:

(a / 24 x 100) / b

`a` should be a dynamic variable, which has multiple values, like 23, 5, 18.
In my case, `a` has 3 numbers (but it could be more or less). So that should be:

((23 / 24 x 100) + (5 / 24 x 100) + (18 / 24 x 100)) / 3

`b` = how many values `a` has. In my case 3.

Is it possible to find a dynamic way the way I want it?

Comment: This sounds like a programming question to me.  You might have better luck on stackoverflow.

Comment: @saulspatz true, I might be thinking like a programmer but I am just wondering if there could be a mathematical solution. If not, maybe there is an alternative way.